# is there any benefit in dropping store procedures and then recreating instead of just altering them

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I may have been mislead by my previous manager that I should drop a store procedure then recreate it instead of just altering, as this ensures it isn't cached. Is there any truth in this?

Comment: Yes - you were mislead. The better approach is as Pred wrote. And a better question is why you think you need to do this generally? Are you attempting to solve a problem?

Comment: no. I saw another developer just alter the sp instead of recreating it. Knowing what my manager was like I was curious if he had any logic to his approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to drop and recreate it, you can safely alter the SP. You can also run `sp_recompile` to force SQL Server to recompile the SP and `sp_refreshsqlmodule` to update their metadata.

SQL Server recompiles triggers, views and SPs automatically when it is advantageous to do this).

Side effects of dropping and re-creating objects:

- object_id of the object will change
- schema binding might prevent you dropping an SP without dropping/altering all dependent objects
- permissions granted to the object specifically will be lost (you have to grant the privileges to the users again). This is only applicable when the privilege is granted/denied specifically for the object
- different DDL triggers will be fired
- ...

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a stored procedure, it will always run the queries, so query results are not cached, but execution plans and indexes will be cached. As a result, it makes sense to remove the stored procedure and recreate it instead of caching it. So all the optimisations which come from compiling the query might be deprecated when you alter the stored procedure, although, altered stored procedure should yield the results you expect from them, provided that you did not make a mistake while altering it.